# If a problem C is NP hard and there is an existing reduction from/to A,B,D, are they NP hard as well?

Tags: reductions, np-hard

Lets say there is an reduction in polynomial time from problem A to B, from problem B to C and from problem C to D. Now lets say C is NP hard. Does this mean A,B,D are NP hard as well?

Comment: I suggest you refresh the basic definitions and remember the intuition that X reduces to Y means that solving Y is at least as hard as solving X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a reduction (many-to-one polynomial time) from a problem (or language) $A$ to a problem $B$, denoted $A \leq_{\textsf{p}}^{\textsf{m}} B$, if there exists a function $f$, computable in polynomial time in the size of the entry, so that $x\in A \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in B$.

It means that if you are able to solve any instance of the problem $B$, then for an instance $x$ of the problem $A$, you can transform it into $f(x)$, solve it like a problem of $B$, and it gives you the answer for the instance $x$.

In your case, if $A \leq_{\textsf{p}}^{\textsf{m}} B \leq_{\textsf{p}}^{\textsf{m}} C \leq_{\textsf{p}}^{\textsf{m}} D$ and $C$ is $\textsf{NP}$-hard, then it implies that $D$ is $\textsf{NP}$-hard. But if $C$ is $\textsf{NP}$, it implies that $A$ and $B$ are $\textsf{NP}$ (since hardness gives a lower bound and $\textsf{NP}$ gives an upper bound).

You can find a reference in the [Arora-Barak](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf), page 59 of the pdf, or the [Cormen-Leiserson-Rivest-Stein](http://web.karabuk.edu.tr/hakankutucu/CME222/MIT[1].Press.Introduction.to.Algorithms.2nd.Edition.eBook-TLFeBOOK.pdf), page 992 of the pdf.

Comment: So if $C$ is NP hard, it only implies that $D$ is in NP. It does not tell anything about $A$ and $B$ right?

Comment: Yup, that's it!